# CoffeeScript - how to avoid unnecessary returns?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Here's my CoffeeScript code:

```
http.createServer((req, res) ->
  if req.method is "POST"
    req.on "data", (data) ->
      queryData += data
    req.on "end", ->
      _.process req.url.substring(1), queryData, (response) ->
        res.writeHead 200,
          "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
        fs.appendFile "./log", log, (err) ->
          if err
            console.log err
          else
            res.end response
  else
    res.writeHead 405,
      "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    res.end()
).listen 55385, "127.0.0.1"
```

Here's what I'm getting compiled:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    req.on("data", function(data) {
      return queryData += data;
    });
    return req.on("end", function() {
      return _.process(req.url.substring(1), queryData, function(response) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
        });
        return fs.appendFile("./log", log, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          } else {
            return res.end(response);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(405, {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    });
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(55385, "127.0.0.1");
```

As you see, it's superfluous 'cause of plenty `returns`.

**I know about coffeescript-trick with void `return` on the last line, but after inserting so many void returns, the code becomes larger than compiled.**

Are there any ways to generate valid Node.JS code without extra returns?

Comment: Is it just size you are worried about? If you gzip your files it probably wont make much of a difference to add the return statements.

Comment: @loganfsmyth not about size itself, but about readability. CoffeeScript is about `readability`, and a lot of returns with strict indent levels don't improve it.

Comment: Oh I understand that, I was just trying to figure out why you were worried about all of the ending returns, since as the accepted answer says, they probably won't change the functionality of anything.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes, you are right. I just worried about if these `returns` may break the logic.

Comment: I'm a bit curious. What logic would break from having a return statement? If you are expecting a null (undefined) return value then explicitly place that code in; otherwise, I can not imagine a problem with it. All functions return something it's just a matter of what. Since the value of the last statement has already been created whether it's returned or not it is irrelevant. The value will be garbage collected anyway. Unless, you use the return value in which case you needed it in the first place. In other words a `"value"; return;` is no different then `return "value";`.

Comment: FYI a function can return undefined if the last statement is a conditional and doesn't offer an *else* clause: `-> "value is not returned" if false` returns undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point is that the returns *are* there. CoffeeScript is designed to facilitate a functional style of programming, where you probably should be returning something from your functions. Embrace it!

Comment: +1 JavaScript has no notion of void returns anyway, all functions return the language value type 'undefined' , the only difference is that coffeescript returns the last statement instead. If you don't want to use the return vlaue just don't use it, it doesn't cost more.

Answer (score 0):

`return` at the end of the code block where you don't want a `return` statement to appear.

```
queryData += data
return
```

Comment: As I wrote above, «I know about coffeescript-trick with void return on the last line, but after inserting so many void returns, the code becomes larger than compiled.»